# Subset a data frame on two conditions exclusively for each row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have a data frame from which I want to extract rows with a specific value in one column and another specific value in the other column. I want to go from df to df_final like in the code below:

```
x = c(25,25,25,25,44,44,44,44,44,76,76)
y = c(1,2,3,4,1,4,6,7,9,4,3)


df<- data.frame(x,y)

df1 <- df %>% filter(x == 25 & y == 2)
df2 <- df %>% filter(x == 44 & y == 6)
df3 <- df %>% filter(x == 76 & y == 3)

df_final <- rbind(df1,df2,df3)


# desired result:

print(df_final)
   x y
1 25 2
2 44 6
3 76 3
```

I have tried using filter with dplyr, but dplyr matches everything within filtered x and y, resulting in too many rows, demonstrated below:

```
df_final <- df %>% filter(x %in% c(25,44,76) & y %in% c(2,6,3))


# non-desired result:

print(df_final)
   x y
1 25 2
2 25 3
3 44 6
4 76 3
```

Is there a way to match exclusively using dplyr? The first instance in filtered x to the first in filtered y, the second instance in filtered x to the second in filtered y and so on... (Other packages than dplyr is also ok of course)

Comment: You can use `df %>% filter(x == 25 & y == 2 | x == 44 & y == 6 | x == 76 & y == 3)` but I suppose you are looking for a different approach.

Comment: Thank you @Let'stry it gets a bit too long for my data, and I can't hard code it all, but I def see your logic behind it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make 1 condition and then use `eval` and `parse`:

```
x_cond <- c(25, 44, 76)
y_cond <- c(2, 6, 3)
final_cond <- map2_chr(x_cond, y_cond, ~str_c("x == ", .x, " & y == ", .y)) %>%
  str_c(collapse = " | ")
df %>% filter(eval(parse(text = final_cond)))
```